# Why does my application close immediately after launching

Tags: python, tkinter

I am a beginner to python language. I have two questions.

1. **When I run auto-py-to-exe my application does not work correctly.**

Up to line 8 of my code I want user to select the .csv file to upload to the py program. After running the auto-py-to-exe, the application closes and does not let the user select the file to upload.

What am I missing in my code to have the application stay open until the user selects the required file, then run the rest of the code?

when running this py.file in `pycharm` it works as it should.

This next question is un-related t this topic but...

2. **How to i pass a filename dynamically?**

In line 33 of my code I will be writing a specially formatted .csv as result.csv to a local dir. How do I pass the variable "filename" as a filename in the path statement in line 33.

`df.to_csv('C:\WriteFilesHere\ result.csv')`

When I run the program it always overwrites `"result.csv"` with the new file selected in line 8 of my code. I want a new file create with a different name every time I run the program.

```
from tkinter import *
import pandas as pd
import csv
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

Tk().withdraw()
filename = askopenfilename()
print(filename)

with open('preliminary.csv', 'w') as output:
    with open(filename) as csv_file:
        output_data = csv.writer(output, delimiter=",")
        data = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        line_count = 0
        for row in data:

            if line_count == 0:
                output_data.writerow(row)
                line_count += 1
            else:
                output_data.writerow(row)
                line_count += 1
with open("preliminary.csv") as readfile:
    reader1 = csv.reader(readfile)
    read =[]
    for row in reader1:
        if len(row) !=0:
            read = read +[row]
readfile.close()
pd.set_option('display.max_rows',4000)
df = pd.DataFrame(read)
print(df)
df.to_csv('C:\WriteFilesHere\ result.csv')
```

Comment: Then instead of hard-coding the filename, you generate it. Maybe based on date/time?

Comment: For Windows, you will need to re-bundle your application with the [Console Based] option. Then you can run the resulting executable from the [command line](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-open-command-prompt-2618089) to see any error output.

Answer (score 0):

About the exe, you can declare a variable and add at the end of your program:

```
DonotClose=input("press close to exit")
```

It will pause the program, you can use any variable you like.